# Dimensiones porcentuales wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, axml

Estoy diseñando una interface con WPF, tengo el gran inconveniente de que al pedir que inicie maximizada, se pierde el tamaño con el que he maquetado y por ende se desordenan los controles que uso, existe alguna forma de que el ancho y alto de la grid o cualquier contenedor que se pueda usar se adapte al 100% de cualquier pantalla?

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Dashboard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded_1"
    xmlns:rg="clr-namespace:SourceChord.ResponsiveGrid;assembly=ResponsiveGrid.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Foreground="White"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Width="1200"
    Height="810"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None">

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="810" Margin="0,-10,2,2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="-5,10,0,768">Button1</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,768">Button2</Button>
</Grid>
```

Tengo un par de botones que ubico en la parte superior de la grid pero al desplegar la aplicación quedan fuera de la pantalla, lo que requiero es una grid u otro control que pueda adaptarse a los tamaños.

Comment: Sería bueno probablemente que agregaras un [mcve] para ejemplificar tu problema.

Comment: Editado, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para eso está el grid, puedes meter grids dentro de grids.

Comment: Los `margin` con unidades fijas pueden estar dandote problemas. Trata siempre de usar posiciones relativas.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te ha dicho [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) deberias de evitar poner las posiciones fijas con los margin.

> Margin="-5,10,0,768"

Para poder hacer lo que quieres, lo suyo sería hacer como te comenta tambien [@Luis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/59172/luis) y podrías meter Grid dentro de Grid tantos como necesites, o si te es más sencillo, meter tantas columnas y/o filas como necesites.

Un ejemplo básico sería algo como:

```
    <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinition>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
    
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Esto es un Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Esto es un Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
     <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinition>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
      <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Command="" />
      <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Espero que te sirva. Si tienes algún problema, especifica un poco mas con alguna imagen de como quieres que te quede y como lo tienes y se le echa un ojo.
Un saludo.